# numba caching issue: cannot cache function / no locator available for file

Tags: numba

I am trying to deploy a codebase that has a number `numba.njit` functions with `cache=True`.

It works fine running locally (Mac OS X 10.12.3), but on the remote machine (Ubuntu 14.04 on AWS) I am getting the following error:

```
RuntimeError at /portal/

cannot cache function 'filter_selection': 

no locator available for file:
'/srv/run/miniconda/envs/mbenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mproj/core_calcs/filter.py'
```

I looked through the numba codebase, and I saw this file: https://github.com/numba/numba/blob/master/numba/caching.py

It appears that the following function is returning None instead of a locator, for this exception to be raised

`cls.from_function(py_func, source_path)`

Guessing this is a permission to write the **pycache** folders, but I didn't see in the numba docs a way to specify the cache folder location (CACHE_DIR).

Has anyone hit this before, and if so, what is the suggested work-around?

Comment: I'm not sure if this solves your problem, but there is a `NUMBA_CACHE_DIR` env variable: https://github.com/numba/numba/blob/d33dbb475f1851d70f2f0f983f9382d12a4042a4/numba/config.py#L121

Comment: Thanks Josh. I eventually got around this issue by changing the permissions of the user running the application to allow access to write the default directories, so I didn't check your suggestion.

Comment: Hi Greg, which permissions did you change. I'm trying to run some software which uses numba on work cluster and am getting a similar error.

Answer (score 2):

Set `sys.frozen = True` before `for cls in self._locator_classes:` in `caching.py` can eliminate the issue.

I have no idea whether such setting will impact performance.